# How to integrate different modules with Entity Framework development?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I would like to start a reasonably big ASP.NET application with Entity Framework.

My question is if i would like to develop via modules
Say for Institute Application
1. Admission Module
2. Fees Module
3. Attendance Module

how do i integrate them in one application with the facility to enable and disable a module at administrator's requirements.

DB SQl Server 2008

if any one can guide on it please

Comment: Well, it might help if you understood what it was you were asking.  You tagged your question asp.net, but your title talks about EF.  Then your question body doesn't mention anything about databases at all..

Comment: thanks Mystere Man, I would like to use SQl Server as Backend Database and develop the total application on modules basis

Answer (score 1):

Hope this document will help you:

http://www.squarewidget.com/pluggable-architecture-in-asp.net-mvc-4

Comment: can you tell something without MVC